# ng-init fetches value only once, even if the model value changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a `status` filed deep nested to 3 levels in my model, I want to apply different classes to a div based on the value of the `status`. In order the save the typing and keep the html tidy, I wanted to apply short name to this status so I used `ng-init` to copy the values and use `ng-class` on `ng-init` variable. But `ng-init` gets its value only once, when I change the status again in controller it doesnt change but holds the old value. **Is there a way to give short names to `response.obj1.obj2.status` at least inside a div?**

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="statusCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">toggle</button>
    <div id="section1" ng-init="s1Status=response.section1.status">
        <div id="statusIndicator" ng-class="{'success':s1Status==0,'error':s1Status==1}">Status</div>
        </div>
<span>{{response.section1.status}}</span>

    </div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('statusCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.response = {
        section1: {
            status: 1
        }
    };
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        if ($scope.response.section1.status === 0) $scope.response.section1.status = 1;
        else $scope.response.section1.status = 0;
    }

});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ES7rgf97BPFAWzkfIEhw?p=preview

EDIT:

***Knockout JS*** has nice way to do this, where you can bind a model at any level to a div and any models referred inside that div will work with the parnet model as context. Thats what I'm looking for.

```
<div id="section1" data-bind="response.section1">
        <div id="statusIndicator" data-bind=" css:{success:status==0, error:status=1 }">Status</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: but where it should react for your changes ? in your opinion ?

Comment: By definition ng-init is used to initialize some variables and it will be called only once. if you want the value of **s1Status** to change on whenever response.section1.status changes, then use watch

Comment: @CodingNinja My main aim is to have shorter variable name in ng-class. Actually the status chnages as new data is fetched from server, so In my case 'watch' would,i think, be an overkill for just to have a short name.

Comment: How about something like $scope.currentSection = $scope.response.section1 inside the controller?

Comment: @GruffBunny If no other choice I shall consider that (I have at least 4 status indicators on the screen :(). Knockout JS has nice way to do this, where you can bind a model at any level to a div and any models referred inside that div will work with the parnet model as context. Thats what I'm looking for

Comment: having `$scope.currentSection = $scope.response.section1` in controller is same as doing `ng-init="s1Status=response.section1.status"` in template
both will set the value of **s1Status** only once, and it will not bind the value